# How to assert if two vectors are equal in CppUnitTest framework

Tags: assert, stdvector, microsoft-cpp-unit-test

I am trying to assert 2-D vectors as shown below

```
TEST_METHOD(TestCase1)
{
    std::vector<int> arr{2};
    int sum{ 2 };
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> subsets;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> expected{ {2} };
    generate_subsets(subsets, arr, sum);
    Assert::AreEqual<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>(subsets, expected);
}
```

But it shows an error as below

```
Error - C2338 Test writer must define specialization of ToString<const Q& q> for your class class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > __cdecl Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString<class std::vector<class std::vector<int,class…
```

Any suggestion would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Assert::AreEqual` wants to convert the values to `std::wstring` for display in case of failure i.e:

```
Assert failed. Expected:<some value> Actual:<some other value>
```

the compiler complains because there is no built in conversion for the type you're using.

A quick fix would be to use `Assert::IsTrue` instead, since it won't try to convert the values to strings:

```cpp
Assert::IsTrue(subsets == expected, L"Unexpected value for <subsets>);
```

If you are going to be comparing these types a lot and want `Assert::AreEqual` to show the actual values when a test fails, then you can do what the compile message suggests and create a `ToString` override for that specific type:

```cpp
#include <CppUnitTestAssert.h>

namespace Microsoft {
    namespace VisualStudio {
        namespace CppUnitTestFramework {
            template<> static inline std::wstring ToString(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &object)
            {
                // Insert some code here to convert <object> to wstring
                return std::wstring();
            }
        }
    }
}
```